# computation of several gradients in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm trying to compute the gradients of the output neurons of a convolutional neural network with respect to the input (pixels of the image). I am currently computing these sequentially by using the tf.gradients function for each output neuron:

```
input_cnn = session.graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
output_cnn = session.graph.get_tensor_by_name("softmax2_pre_activation:0")

output_scalars = [tf.slice(output_cnn, [0, i], [1, 1]) for i in range(0, NUM_CLASSES)]
dydx = [tf.gradients(output_scalars[i], [input_cnn])[0] for i in range(0, NUM_CLASSES)]
```

The execution of the last line takes however *a lot* of time (half an hour on a standard GPU for NUM_CLASSES = 1000). Moreover, the computation of a gradient dydx[i] for the first time in a Python session takes a signficant amount of time. Later calls of dydx[i] in the same session are however very fast:

```
>> session.run(dydx[123], feed_dict={input_cnn: im1}) # Very slow
>> session.run(dydx[123], feed_dict={input_cnn: im2}) # Fast
```

Is there a more efficient way to compute these gradients (i.e., the Jacobian matrix)? The above approach doesn't seem to be optimal at all, as all dydx[i] are generated independently...

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675), this is one of the early design flaw of TF. An alternative would be using Theano.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can define your gradients as:

```
dydx = tf.gradients([output_scalars[i] for i in range(0, NUM_CLASSES)], [input_cnn])[0])
```

with possibly some resizes (I don't know, as I don't know the sizes of `input_cnn` and `output_scalars`).

Then, you can calculate all dydx together:

```
res = session.run(dydx, feed_dict=...)
```

A single run of calculating `dydx` should be around 1.5 to 2 times slower than a single calculation of `dydx[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I can see from the documentation that tf.gradients computes the *sum* of gradients of ys with respect to x, when its first argument is a list of tensors. This is different from the required Jacobian.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the docs. Still, if you evaluate `dydx` as I described, you should experience a speed boost.